# how to "normalize" query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which shows different values per timestamp. A line is inserted into the table each time the value has changed (like a thermometer controller).

Showing the records will result only the changes and the timestamps. My problem is that I need to show the results per minute or so even if the value hasn't been change at all. And  without inserting "blank" lines into the table.

I tried to right join my table with a view that shows all the `getdate()` stamps from the same date but I couldn't get the query to work.

```
05 Sep 2016 09:50:24    20
05 Sep 2016 09:56:14    18
```

should be

```
05 Sep 2016 09:50:24    20
05 Sep 2016 09:51:24    20
05 Sep 2016 09:52:24    20
05 Sep 2016 09:53:24    20
05 Sep 2016 09:54:24    20
05 Sep 2016 09:55:24    20
05 Sep 2016 09:56:14    18
05 Sep 2016 09:57:24    18
.
.
```

Comment: One option here would be to have a date/time table which you use to fill in the missing data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use recursive CTE. I assume that columns are called `ChangedDate` for datetime and `SomeValue` for whatever value in second column in your question.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  t.ChangedDate,
        t.SomeValue,
        p.ChangedDate as NextDate
FROM YourTable t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT top 1 *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE t.ChangedDate <ChangedDate
    ORDER BY ChangedDate
    ) p
UNION ALL
SELECT  DATEADD(minute,1,ChangedDate),
        SomeValue,
        NextDate
FROM cte
WHERE DATEADD(minute,1,ChangedDate) < NextDate
)

SELECT  ChangedDate,
        SomeValue
FROM cte
ORDER BY ChangedDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

For your sample it will output:

```
ChangedDate             SomeValue
2016-09-05 09:50:24.000 20
2016-09-05 09:51:24.000 20
2016-09-05 09:52:24.000 20
2016-09-05 09:53:24.000 20
2016-09-05 09:54:24.000 20
2016-09-05 09:55:24.000 20
2016-09-05 09:56:14.000 18
```

If you add one more string like `('2016-09-05 10:00:34',    17)`, it will output:

```
ChangedDate             SomeValue
2016-09-05 09:50:24.000 20
2016-09-05 09:51:24.000 20
2016-09-05 09:52:24.000 20
2016-09-05 09:53:24.000 20
2016-09-05 09:54:24.000 20
2016-09-05 09:55:24.000 20
2016-09-05 09:56:14.000 18
2016-09-05 09:57:14.000 18
2016-09-05 09:58:14.000 18
2016-09-05 09:59:14.000 18
2016-09-05 10:00:14.000 18
2016-09-05 10:00:34.000 17
```

If you need this log to last till current time change this part:

```
p.ChangedDate as NextDate
```

in CTE on this:

```
COALESCE(p.ChangedDate,GETDATE()) as NextDate
```